# SharePoint Online: some users see the internal column names in views

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-name, internal-name

I have a SharePoint online solution with several users.  Most of my columns have display names different from the internal column names.

Now, for some strange reason, some of my users see my lists and views with internal column names , some see the same lists with the display names on the user interface.

I believe everyone is supposed to see the display names.

Does someone have an idea what I could do to fix this?

It is not a browser issue, I tried logging in from several different machines and I keep getting the same result.

Comment: Is your site multilanguage? Can your users choose the display language?

Comment: Yes it is. I have tried changing the language of the user, but that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: did you deployed the columns using declarative or programatic? When editing the column in the address bar do you see the same internal name as display name?

Comment: I created the list with SharePoint Designer. I saw the internal names when I clicked "Modify View".

Comment: Sorry, my first comment is incorrect. Changing the user langauge does fix the problem, but it takes a bit of time to take effect. The only remaining question is if it is possible to have the display names with my language (Hungarian)  .   If someone else has the same problem : make sure that your users have the exact same language set in their user profile than the user that created the site.

Comment: I am having the same issue here.
Could you explain how and where do users need to change the language to display the correct names? I tried changing mine in the browser and in myaccount.microsoft.com to recreate the problem but I keep viewing everything correctly. Also I was wondering if this issue could cause other problems. In my case, the sharepoint list is connected to some flows and the from is customized using powerapps.There are some weird bugs that happened only to the one user who sees the internal names of the columns...